# Filtrar lista jquery com checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esta função que faz o filtro de uma tabela, conforme o campo select selecionado e o que foi digitado no input, e funciona.

```
  function myFunction2() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, filtro;
  input = document.getElementById("busca2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("tablepesquisa2");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  filtro = document.getElementById("filtroPesquisa2").value;

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Porém eu tenho um `checkbox` e queria que se ele tivesse como `true`, ele filtrasse o campo tipo produto na tabela, como posso proceder? 
Aqui é o HTML da minha `table`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <select id="filtroPesquisa2" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">Código</option>
      <option value="1">Descrição</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" id="busca2" placeholder="Pesquisa.." onkeyup="myFunction2();" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="table-overflow col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tablepesquisa2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Código</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Produto) {
        <tr>
          <td>@item.Codigo</td>
          <td>@item.nome</td>
          <td align="right">
            <a href="#" onclick="fecha2();CarregaProduto('@item.Codigo');" title="Selecionar"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        }

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esse é o checkbox:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:left;">
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="Produtos" onclick="checkProduto();" name="Produtos" id="Produtos"/>
<label asp-for="Produtos" class="control-label"></label>
<span asp-validation-for="Produtos" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:left;">
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="Servico" onclick="checkServico();" name="Servico" id="Servico"/>
<label asp-for="Servico" class="control-label"></label>
<span asp-validation-for="Servico" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Queria desta forma: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50183/72989), porém com os filtros que já existem no meu formulário, não estou conseguindo adaptar, pois não entendi muito bem o código.

Eu cheguei nesta função, ela não retorna erro, porém não trás os campos conforme o checkbox:

```
function VerificaCheck() { 
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, filtro;
        input = document.getElementById("busca2");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("tablepesquisa2");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        filtro = document.getElementById("filtroPesquisa2").value;
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro];
            var tipoProduto = td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")["tipoProduto"];
            if (td) {
                if (tipoProduto == $('#Produtos').prop("checked")) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: E se você adicionar a condição `if ($('#SEUCHECK').prop("checked")) {}` no momento da montagem do filtro? Ai poderá manipular suas cláusulas

Comment: Não estou entendendo a forma de fazer isso, como filtrar depois.

Comment: Ele verifica direto no HTML da coluna e torna visível cada linha da sua tabela onde tenha o texto digitado no input como pode ver nessa linha `if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)`. As linhas que nao tiverem a busca ficam invisíveis.

Comment: Sim, até ai eu entendi o código, e funciona, porém ele vai fazer o filtro do que estiver digitado, e do checkbox também, não sei como implementar @VictorLaio

Comment: Te atenderia adicionar uma nova coluna com o Tipo do Produto e pudesse filtrar como os outros filtros já funcionam?

Comment: Atenderia sim, o campo é do tipo bool.

Comment: @VictorLaio e se filtrasse primeiro ao clicar no checkbox, e depois deixasse essa função desta forma, seria mais fácil, não é ? Estou tentando fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você deve adicionar um *input hidden* em suas linhas para puxar esse valor diretamente no filtro contendo o valor do seu Tipo Produto (Dentro da seu *for* mesmo):

```js
@foreach (var item in Model.Produto) {
    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" id="tipoProduto" value="@item.TipoProduto" />
      <td>@item.Codigo</td>
      <td>@item.nome</td>
      <td align="right">
        <a href="#" onclick="fecha2();CarregaProduto('@item.Codigo');" title="Selecionar"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Depois basta modificar o seu método de pesquisa myFunction2():

```js
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro];
    tipoProduto = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && tipoProduto == $('#Produtos').prop("checked")) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
```

O raciocínio é mais ou menos esse, talvez você tenha que fazer alguma alteração para caber em seu código e sua necessidade. Mas a idéia foi passada.

Espero que te ajude, qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Comment: Ele está retornando o seguinte erro: tr[i].getElementById is not a function

Comment: Nesta linha `tipoProduto = tr[i].getElementById("tipoProduto").value;`

Comment: Alterei para pegar o elemento pelo tipo input agora

Comment: Mesmo problema, estou colocando ele dentro do `td` pra ver se resolve o problema.

Comment: Ele tem que estar dentro do tr pro getElementsByTagName() funcionar.

Comment: Mas ele está, estou até tentando separar somente pro checkbox pra ver se vai funcionar.

Comment: Realmente não funcionou, ele sempre retorna erro nesta linha, tentei de várias formas.

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações, porém a lógica foi esta, obrigado.

Comment: Não porisso! Estou a disposição!